# Synchronizing Xamarin file data between devices of the same platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I’m working on a Xamarin application. So far it works quite well and I can test it on Windows and Android. Since I have no mac, I cannot test it on this platform so far.
The application holds its data in a single file which is loaded and saved directly in the device's file system.
One of the the last steps to finalize the application is now, that I have to synchronize the data file between devices, so that the app can be installed on multiple devices, and on all devices the data is available.

**My question is, if there is a simple mechanism that can be used, to synchronize the data file within instances of the application on multiple devices on the same platform.** To me it seems clear, that when I want to support the synchronization over different platforms (iOS to android, UWP to iOS, etcetera), that I have to use some external data storage service such as one drive, google drive, iCloud or to provide an own storage service such as a webservice on Azure or S3 (please correct me, if my assumption is wrong).

However to start, **is there a mechanism in Xamarin, which uses the platform's own synchronization mechanisms, which are available in a unified way through the Xamarin environment**?
Currently I use for my local file the `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` enum value. Are there locations, which are automatically synched between devices (of the same platform)? Or have I to implement storage logic for each platform?
For iOS I found the `UIDocument` storage. If I have to go down this track, what would be the appropriate service for the various platforms, if there are any?

Comment: AFAIK, No. If there is a way, it isn't in Xamarin.Forms - there's no "unified" answer. You'd have to google each platform for a solution. Then write a [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) on each platform, to use that platform-specific code. OR investigate one of the cloud services (e.g. Google FireBase or Cloud Functions); and solve it cross-platform. E.g. Write "cloud functions" that do what you want, and pay for cloud storage.